# How to perform 'insert rows' instead of 'copy rows' using CopyFromRecordset(excel vba)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, export-to-excel

I am new to excel VBA. I have a requirement where I have to copy table values from sql server 2005 to an excel worksheet. I have googled and written a code for the above requirement (listed below).

In this excel sheet there are fixed set of rows which displays legends and dates. These rows should be displayed after the database/table values are printed. As I am using .CopyFromRecordset to copy the records from the recordset to excel sheet, the rows which are displaying legend and dates are overwritten with the database/table values. Please let me know how to perform insert of rows instead of copy. Or is there any way to achieve the above.

---CODE------------

```
Sub GETSQLSERVERDATA()
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim USERID As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

USERID = Range("C1").Value 'Input form excel template.
Server_Name = "" 'Enter server name
Database_Name = "" 'Enter database name
User_ID = "" 'SQL server user id
Password = "" SQL server password

SQLStr = "SELECT END_DATE,PERIOD FROM PERIOD_MAP WHERE USERID='" + USERID + "'"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"  
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D2") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
    .ClearContents
    .CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: before you run `.CopyFromRecordset method` you need to check number of rows there are in you `rs variable`. Then insert appropriate number of rows before and then run the method...

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the row before copying the rs?

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D2").Row).Insert _
            Shift:=xlDown, _
            CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: And like @KazJaw mentioned, insert as many rows as records in your recordset.

Comment: Thank you KazJaw and @Raybarg for the help. Now I am able to insert the records.